# Returning [object HTMLDivElement] while using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using javascript to write content to a iframe using text file .

`var fs = require('fs');     //file read module
 global.content = fs.read('post.txt');`

when i try to write content to innerHTML of the para using this :

`var write = ifrm.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; 
 write.innerHTML = content;`

it returns [object HTMLDivElement] .

Why is this happening ? Any solution ?

Comment: What is `content`? Where do you define it in your code? What is the expected result?

Comment: `global.content = fs.read('post.txt');`

Answer (score 1):

`write` is an object, you assign it to a property that is calling `toString()` on it, and that is the object's string representation.

You may want...

```
write.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
```